# Trying to get one shape to show depending on chosen radio button

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am using raphael.js to draw shapes depending on which radio button is chosen, but I only want one shape to show at a time. When I click on the radio button I'm getting all shapes at once and when I click on another radio button the shapes get re-drawn.  Would really appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
    <input name="shapes" id="square" type="radio">
    <label for="square">Square</label>
    <input name="shapes" id="rectangle" type="radio">
    <label for="rectangle">Rectangle</label>
    <input name="shapes" id="circle" type="radio">
    <label for="circle">Circle</label>
```

raphael/jquery

```
    $(':radio[name="shapes"]').on('click', function(){
       var shapeName = $(this).attr('id');

       var square = p.rect(10,10,40,40);
       var rectangle = p.rect(20,20,50,80);
       var circle = p.circle(40,40,10);

       console.log(shapeName);
       return shapeName;

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':radio[name="shapes"]').on('click', function(){
   var shapeName = $(this).attr('id');
   if(shapeName == "square")
       p.rect(10,10,40,40);
   else if(shapeName == "rectangle")
       p.rect(20,20,50,80);
   else if(shapeName == "circle")
       p.circle(40,40,10);

   console.log(shapeName);
   return shapeName;

});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for getting all the shapes not to show at once, now I just need to figure out how to get just one shape to show at a time.  Thanks Again!

Comment: Are the shapes showing at all? I could not get the raphael library to work in jsfiddle. If they are showing, but not disappearing you might have to draw over it with a the shape the same color as background or reload the place where it is drawn.

Comment: Yes, each shape appears when the corresponding button is clicked but remains after another button is clicked.  I think I need to assign the shape an node.id and hide() that id when another button is clicked.

Comment: I agree with assigning an id and hiding it. You could draw all the shapes first and hide them. and show and hide the ones you want in the if else statements.

Comment: Im will end up having 200-300 shapes, do you think this will cause a performance issue?  I suppose I could do a loop and remove() all but the currently selected shape?

Comment: I don't think the large amount of shapes will have that big of a preformance issue.